# I want to make the to_hdf function which save the data of MonteCarloRunnerClass

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdf

I want to make a function which will save the data when we call upon.
the link to class is:

[MonteCarloRunner class](http://pastebin.com/Tu05byVV)

I made the to_hdf() function but it is not saving the data just creating a hdf file. Help me to put the data to that hdf file by going through the code.

Comment: You need something like `hdf.append('df', YourDataframe)` before you close the datastore (variable `hdf` is your datastore).

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.append.html#pandas.HDFStore.append

Comment: i need to store the properties return by `legacy_return` function, before closing the hdf store. can u give the line of code to do that i.e before line 132 (hdf.close() ) function